# How to allow access to domain from subdomain in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Using nginx, I have an html file served at `sub.example.com` which needs to get its json data from `example.com`

But the json is not loaded. Instead, in Chrome browser I get:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://sub.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CORS headers on your example.com server to allow the domain sub.example.com to use this resource, for example:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://sub.example.com" always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Content-Type, Accept" always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE" always;
```

OR

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://*.example.com" always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Content-Type, Accept" always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE" always;
```

You need to set it in a server that handles the Json. You can allow * in CORS, but it isn't recommended.

Comment: Why it is not recommended?

Comment: CORS is a feature of the browser to protect use of resources Cross-Domain. So, you can set the header to allow '*', but doing it you allow any site to user your Json. If your Json is not private you can.

Comment: I don't think 'https://*.example.com' works as intended. It requires FQDN. I see following error: `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://*.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'https://something.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`